# Will truncate in ScyllaDB also delete data on other nodes

Tags: scylla

I have three nodes running, which contain some data we need to purge. Since we can not identify the records, we would like to truncate the table and fill it from scratch.

Now I was wondering, when I issue a `truncate` statement, will this only truncate the current instance or will this also clear the other nodes?

So basically, do I have to issue the `truncate` statement on each node and also fill it there, or is it sufficient to do it on one node and it will propagte to the others. We would load the data from a `CSV` file via the `COPY` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table will be truncated in the entire cluster.